# ckeditor add "<body id="cke_pastebin" > </body>" tag

Tags: javascript, html, ckeditor

I am using ckeditor for my project. Whenever I am going to add some text which contain HTML tag in ckeditor then it add below string in my HTML pasted string.

```
<body id="cke_pastebin" 
      style="position: absolute; top: 21px; width: 1px; 
             height: 1px; overflow-x: hidden; overflow-y: hidden; 
             left: -1000px; ">
</body>
```

I tried there given patch for above issue but it works only for IE not for Crome browser.I used there updated version in my demo project but no success.

Comment: What patch is it?

Comment: https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor-dev/commit/7bbcff165fac497f9faa979969a0cd1fdc12efeb

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problems you are referring to were fixed in CKEditor 3.6.4 and 4.0. Please see: https://dev.ckeditor.com/ticket/9042 and https://dev.ckeditor.com/ticket/9549.

If you are using CKEditor below that version **please upgrade the editor** because you will have problems with supporting latest browsers. For example: support for IE0 was introduced in CKE 3.6.5, support for IE 11 in CKEditor 4.3 and support for Edge in CKEditor 4.5.6. Also note that by staying with an older, unsupported version you are missing many important bug fixes (including security-related ones) and new features that your editor users are still not able to use.

I will also add that CKEditor 3.x is no longer developed so **upgrading to CKEditor 4.x is highly recommended**. CKEditor has a very good documentation so it should not be that hard: https://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide, http://sdk.ckeditor.com/index.html

See the following guides:

- [Upgrading from CKEditor 3](https://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_upgrade_ckeditor_3)
- [Upgrading CKEditor](https://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_upgrade) - for version 4

Comment: Yes Issue get resolved when I download latest version of CKEditor.
Thanks @Anna Tomanek for valuable response.

Comment: Thanks @j.swiderski